# How to render Animation with solid shading?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

It´s the first time I´m working with the Video Sequence Editor in Blender 2.79 and it´s realy promising.

But how do I export the whole Sequence as **solid** shaded Animation? Although there is an Option called "Scene Preview/Render" (which is set to solid) blender renders each frame ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes one need some time to find the right button :-)

[image: Blender OpenGL viewport render button]